# Transfer from contract address

Tags: solidity, transactions, ethereum-wallet-dapp, payable

I created a contract with a `payable` function but the ether is stored in the contract I am looking for a way to transfer the ether to another address

Answer (score 13):

If the ether is already in the contract and you do not have the functionality to transfer ether already implemented in it, the ether will be forever in the contract.

A simple contract that receives ether and allows for transferring is shown below. Only the person that deploys the contract will be able to transfer the ether.

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.24; 

contract myContract{

    address public owner;

    constructor() public {
        owner = msg.sender;
    }

    function transfer(address to, uint256 amount) public {
        require(msg.sender==owner);
        to.transfer(amount);
    }

    function () public payable {}
}
```

Hope this helps

Answer (score 4):

You can call the [`receiver.transfer(amount)`](https://solidity.readthedocs.io/en/develop/units-and-global-variables.html?highlight=transfer#address-related) to send the ether in the `receiver`s account

Answer (score 3):

This is how I solve it:

```
function sendMoney(address to, uint value) public {
   address payable receiver = payable(to);
   receiver.transfer(value);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You must have a function in the contract that send ether out of the contract as well. This function does not have to be payable, but would look something like:

```
myAddress.transfer(address(this).balance);
```